# Datarow imported from Excel not returning any value, if data is having '/' in it

Tags: c#, excel

I am trying to read Data from an Excel sheet using C#. But in some of the columns that I am reading is having '/' in the data. Eg: 123456/987654.
I that case, I am only getting spaces. Like the sheet is like this :

111111
222222
123456/987654
333333

I am getting the result like this :
111111
222222

333333

Could you please let me know of the issue/workaround?

```
    var fileName = string.Format("{0}\\ReleaseNoteValidation\\release notes.xlsx", Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());

    string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileName + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";

    var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Latest fixes$]", connectionString);
    var ds = new DataSet();

    adapter.Fill(ds, "releaseNote");

    DataTable data = ds.Tables["releaseNote"];

    Console.WriteLine(data.Rows.Count);

    foreach (DataRow row in data.Rows)
    {
        releaseNoteChangeList.Add(Convert.ToString(row["ChangeID"]));
        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(row["ChangeID"]));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@tafia, Thank you for the reply. As u suggested, i changed all the data to text by changing my connection string.

```
        string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;'";
```

Answer (score 1):

Hard Format all your values as text in the Excel Document and see what happens.
to do this create a column beside the Numeric & AlphaNumeric values and create a formula like =A1&"". Copy and paste values then replace your original columns with your new values and delete the column you just created.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the reply. The issue is fixed buy using almost the same logic which you said. Converted all cells in to text, by changing the `OLEDB` connection string.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` is guessing the column datatype based on the first rows it can read. It assumes the entire column should be numerical.

Thus you don't have a *blank* cell but a `NULL` value as you `/` is not a numeric character.

You must constrain the column to be of type `Text` somehow or do it manually.

I'm not necessarily familiar with ACE but something like `Select Cstr(col) ...` may work.